# Is there an easy way to return to Windows 8 Music app home page?

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt, microsoft-surface, xbox-music

When you first launch the Music app, you see a home screen with tiles featuring your music as well as music available in the cloud as part of the Xbox Music service. As far as I know, the only way to get back to this page is to either close and reopen the app or press the back button until you get there. Both of those options are undesirable. Is there quick and easy way to get back to the home screen?

Comment: This is on the Surface RT or Pro?

Comment: RT. But I believe the music app is the same across all devices.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Microsoft support and was told that there is no other way to get back to the home screen. Either you press the back button a dozen times or close and re-open the app.